# How does JDBC Connection to Sybase in Pentaho Kettle differ depending on the number of databases running in the SQL Anywhere server?

Tags: jdbc, sybase, pentaho, kettle, sqlanywhere

I'm trying to test a Database Connection in Pentaho Kettle to a SQL Anywhere database server on local with the Native (JDBC) connection using the default DBA/sql credentials. The .exe used to run the database server is the classic dbsrv10.exe for SQL Anywhere. It runs on port 2638. When I run dbsrv10.exe with only one database file, Kettle can connect just fine with the credentials on that port, and here's the interesting part, with ANY Database Name.

Once I include two database files, I get a Login Error from Kettle, even when using the appropriate names of each database in the Database Name field (I set the names dbsrv10 uses to refer to each database in the command line or I can omit that and SQL Anywhere refers to them by the file names without the .db). Any thoughts as to what's different and how I can actually connect when dbsrv is managing two databases?

Comment: Could you post the snippet of code and the line on which the error occurs?  You can just dummy up credentials and limit it to the  specific piece.

Comment: Hey Jimmy, no code on this one. All done using the Pentaho Kettle GUI on Windows. I'm just testing the connection using their "Database Connection" tool.